# Robocopy with simple history of files backup

Tags: windows, file, backup, robocopy

do you know how can I use robocopy to make incremental copy ?

A simple example that I would like to have :

```
\\SOURCE : all files 

\\DESTINATION\2016-01-01 : all files
\\DESTINATION\2016-01-02 : only all files modified or created from 2016-01-01
\\DESTINATION\2016-01-03 : only all files modified or created from 2016-01-02
etc...
```

Thanks for help,

Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to leverage these switches:

> /MAXAGE:n : MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
>   /MINAGE:n : MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.
>   (If n < 1900 then n = no of days, else n = YYYYMMDD date).

<sub>([More switches to tailor your solution](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html))</sub>

So to do something historical

```
ROBOCOPY \\Source \\DESTINATION\2016-01-01
ROBOCOPY \\Source \\DESTINATION\2016-01-02 /MINAGE:20160102 /MAXAGE:20160101
ROBOCOPY \\Source \\DESTINATION\2016-01-02 /MINAGE:20160103 /MAXAGE:20160102
```

If it's to take a back up for today this will suffice, on the day of backup:

```
Robocopy \\source \\destination /MAXAGE:1
```

Comment: It's to do a backup of the day, all days :) I will test the maxage option thank you.